# JavaScript Object Allocation Limit at Runtime

Tags: javascript, memory-management

I am working on an application that is very JavaScript heavy. I'm concerned about runtime performance. I'm currently using the "record heap allocations" profiling feature in Google Chrome. My question is, if I am supporting users that will be viewing this app on iOS and Android devices, what is a reasonable acceptable level of memory usage?

Thank you so much

Comment: Is your app already slow? If not, this question is too early.

Comment: FWIW, Chrome's V8 on Android 4.2 starts aggressive garbage collection starting at 10MB, even when my phone has 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be serious - no more than 50 mb - your phone got 2gb but most of it would be used by os on Android. my SGS3 got 1gb ram but only up to 200 mb is free for apps, rest is taken by OS. if we'll assume that Chrome mobile takes another 50 mb, you're quite tight on memory

Comment: and Android will rather kill app than run out of memory, so be careful, there are still phones with 512 or even 256 mb of ram

Comment: 50MB is way too heavy for a JS app. If you want it to run well on mobile, I honestly would make sure to keep it's max usage under 20MB.